# Adding two items in the same Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, collections, meteor

Ok, let me restate the question.  I am new in Meteor and I do not know how to add 
I created a meteor collection called

```
Products1 = new Meteor.Collection ('products1');
```

and in that collection I have several variables which include : "watts" and "wattsbal".

This is a sample of the app  http://orozcotest.meteor.com/products1 (in this webpage I had to store manually the column "Watts totales" by storing the information in `{{wats_tot}}`  this is momentarily while I learn how to add) you can see an updated copy in https://github.com/orozcorp/myapp.git  now I want to add the column "watts" and "watts balastro" which are identified by the variables "watts" and "wattsbal" respectively.  I also have the following template

```
Template.product1Form.events({
    'click .save':function(evt,tmpl){
        var codigo = tmpl.find('.codigo').value;
        var tipo = tmpl.find('.tipo').value;
        var watts = tmpl.find('.watts').value;
        var wattsbal = tmpl.find('.wattsbal').value;
        var watts_tot = tmpl.find('.watts_tot').value;
        var precio = tmpl.find('.precio').value;
        var precio_bal = tmpl.find('.precio_bal').value;
        var numbal = tmpl.find('.numbal').value;
        var mo = tmpl.find('.mo').value;
        var horasvid = tmpl.find('.horasvid').value;
        var lux_watt = tmpl.find('.lux_watt').value;
        if(Session.get('editing_product1')){
            updateProduct1(codigo,watts, tipo, watts_tot, precio, precio_bal, numbal, mo, horasvid, wattsbal, lux_watt);
        } else{
            addProduct1(codigo,watts, tipo, watts_tot, precio, precio_bal, numbal, mo, horasvid, wattsbal, lux_watt);   
        }
        Session.set('showProduct1Dialog',false);
        Session.set('editing_product1',null);
    },
    'click .cancel':function(evt,tmpl){
        Session.set('showProduct1Dialog',false);
        Session.set('editing_product1',null);
    },
    'click .remove':function(evt,tmpl){
        removeProduct1();   
        Session.set('showProduct1Dialog',false);
        Session.set('editing_product1',null);
    }
})
```

Now in my javascript file i have tried all of the following methods and I keep getting undefined or NaN

```
Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales1 : function(){
        var watts = tmpl.find('.watts').value;
        var wattsbal=tmpl.find('.wattsbal').value;
        var wattstotales = Number(watts) + Number (wattsbal);
        return wattstotales;
    }

});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales2 : function(){
        return Session.get('.watts').value + Session.get('.wattsbal').value;
    }

});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales3 : function(){
        var watts = find('.watts').value;
        var wattsbal = find('.wattsbal').value;     
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales4 : function(){
        var watts = Session.get(Number('.watts')).value;
        var wattsbal = Session.get(Number('.wattsbal')).value;  

        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales5 : function(){
        var watts = Number('watts');
        var wattsbal = Number('wattsbal');          
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales6 : function(){
        var watts = Number(Session.get('.watts').value);
        var wattsbal = Number(Session.get('.wattsbal').value);      
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales7 : function(){
        var watts = Number(Session.get('watts').value);
        var wattsbal = Number(Session.get('wattsbal').value);       
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});


Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales8: function () {
        var a = $('products1.watts').val();
        var b = $('products1.wattsbal').val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales9: function () {
        var a = Session.get('products1.watts').val();
        var b = Session.get('products1.wattsbal').val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});

Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales10: function () {
        var a = Session.get(Number('products1.watts')).val();
        var b = Session.get(Number('products1.wattsbal')).val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales11 : function(){
        var watts = tmpl.find('.watts').value;
        var wattsbal=tmpl.find('.wattsbal').value;
        var wattstotales = Number(watts) + Number (wattsbal);
        return wattstotales;
    }

});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales12 : function(){
        return Session.get('.watts').value + Session.get('.wattsbal').value;
    }

});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales13 : function(){
        var watts = find('.watts').value;
        var wattsbal = find('.wattsbal').value;     
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales14 : function(){
        var watts = Session.get(Number('.watts')).value;
        var wattsbal = Session.get(Number('.wattsbal')).value;  

        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales15 : function(){
        var watts = Number('watts');
        var wattsbal = Number('wattsbal');          
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales16 : function(){
        var watts = Number(Session.get('.watts').value);
        var wattsbal = Number(Session.get('.wattsbal').value);      
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales17 : function(){
        var watts = Number(Session.get('watts').value);
        var wattsbal = Number(Session.get('wattsbal').value);       
        return watts+ wattsbal;
    }
});


Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales18: function () {
        var a = $('products1.watts').val();
        var b = $('products1.wattsbal').val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales19: function () {
        var a = Session.get('products1.watts').val();
        var b = Session.get('products1.wattsbal').val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});

Template.products1.helpers ({
    wattstotales20: function () {
        var a = Session.get(Number('products1.watts')).val();
        var b = Session.get(Number('products1.wattsbal')).val();
        var total = a+b;
                return total;       
    }
});
```

Comment: your helper function doesn't return anything. the helper is spelled `watts_total` not `wattstotal`, and the code you are showing doesn't even refer to the collection you mention. Please try to be a bit more precise about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer,

```
    Template.product1Row.helpers ({
    wattstotales : function (){
         var total = Number(this.watts) + Number(this.wattsbal);
         return total;
         }
     })
```